# How many times have the Big 3 lost a 5 set match without earning a break point?

Tags: tennis, atp

On January 26th 2024, Novak Djokovic lost his Australian Open semis match to Yannick Sinner without having earned a single break point. Not only he didn't brake Sinner, he also didn't get a break point! The only set Novak won was on a tie breaker after they bothe held serve during the set.

Given the dominance of the Big 3 in tennis, how many times in their careers have they lost a 5 set match without earning a break point?